# Hide some div on click on body or on other div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance, jquery-ui

```
<div id="container">
    <div class='sub1'></div>
    <div class='sub2'></div>
    <div class='part1'></div>
     <div class='part2'></div>
 </div>
```

and the working is like...
  click on `sub1` will hide `sub1` and `sub2` will show , same as with `part1` and `part2`

ANd What i need is  ... after clicking sub1 (now `sub2` is shown and `sub1` is hide), if i click on body or in `part2` , i need to hide `sub2` and  show `sub1`

The same with `part1` and `part2`.

I tried in different ways using jQuery , but i cant find a good solution...

Please help :)

Comment: Post the code you tried?

Comment: What have you tried? Without any code it's hard to see where in your code you're going wrong.

Comment: its a large bit of code having more inneer tags , thats y i add d sample

Answer (score 2):

Your description of the use case for a click on the "body" is pretty vague, but from what you explain I assume that you need the "states" to toggle. i.e if one is hidden it should be shown, and viceversa. That is what I implemented but it would be easy to change if you need it.

Jfiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/UNCru/1/

And the code:

```
$(".sub1, .sub2, .part1, .part2").click(function(event){
    subClicked($(this));
    event.stopPropagation();
});

$("body").click(bodyClicked);

function subClicked($this)
{
    var $target;
    if ($this.attr("class").indexOf("1") != -1)
    {
        // part1 or sub1
        $target = $('.' + $this.attr("class").replace("1","2"));
    }
    else
    {
        // part2 or sub1
        $target = $('.' + $this.attr("class").replace("2","1"));
    }

    $target.show();
    $this.hide();
}

function bodyClicked()
{
    $(".sub1, .sub2, .part1, .part2").each(function(){
            if ($(this).is(":visible"))
                $(this).hide();
            else
                $(this).show();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to share css rules with the div's I suggest that you use ID's to identify them then you can do:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() // document is loaded and ready
{
   $("#sub1").click(function() 
   {
      $("#sub2").stop(true, true); // stop all animations this is to help minimize 
      $("#sub1").stop(true, true); // overload because of constant clicking
      $("#sub2").show();  $("#sub1").hide() // show div 2 and hide div 1
   })
});
```

same code to change other divs just changing the identifier (it's the one inside the $("") syntax) to part1 or part2. You can do the same with class but the identifier starts with "." instead of "#" but doing it with class identifiers will make all divs with that class hide or show.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple with javascript...

http://jsfiddle.net/MpLFZ/

```
<div id="sub1" onclick="document.getElementById('sub2').style.display = 'block'; document.getElementById('sub1').style.display = 'none';">sub1</div><br />
<div id="sub2" onclick="document.getElementById('sub1').style.display = 'block'; document.getElementById('sub2').style.display = 'none';" style="display:none;">sub2</div>
```